Extract text in-between 2 dates of identical format with python
I want to extract a valid transaction from a bunch of text. Each transaction should start with a date (dd/mm/yyyy) and end before the next date (dd/mm/yyyy). A transaction may have 1 or 2 or more descriptions following the date.
Example of 1 transaction:
03/04/2024 Payments / Collections 10.08 795.04      ---> Date description cost balance
HU INSURANCE UK                                     ---> Description
G0003406201 56171304 2024-04-17                     ---> Description                   
G3406201                                            ---> Description

Input string
input_text = """
02/04/2024 Funds Transfer 56.00 1,805.12
TOP-UP TO WALLET! :
84343571729
02/04/2024 Bill Payment 1,000.00 805.12
UHJN-5520380040396554 : I-BANK
03/04/2024 Payments / Collections 10.08 795.04
HU INSURANCE UK
G0003406201 56171304 2024-04-17
G3406201
04/04/2024 FAST Payment / Receipt 12,000.00 12,795.04
INVEST
20240404CIBBSTSTBRT3273519
OTHER
04/04/2024 Bill Payment 333.00 12,462.04
GBU -09890340922 : I-BANK
30/04/2024 Interest Earned 0.18 2,385.42
"""

My code:
# Regex pattern for dates (dd/mm/yyyy)
date_pattern = r"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}"

# Find all date matches
date_matches = re.findall(date_pattern, input_text)

# Initialize an empty list to store desired output
output = []

# Extract text between dates
for i in range(len(date_matches) - 1):
    start_index = input_text.find(date_matches[i]) + len(date_matches[i])
    end_index = input_text.find(date_matches[i + 1])
    text_between_dates = input_text[start_index:end_index].strip()
    output.append([date_matches[i], text_between_dates])

# Print the desired output
for item in output:
    print(item)

Output result:
['02/04/2024', '']
['02/04/2024', 'Funds Transfer 56.00 1,805.12\nTOP-UP TO WALLET! :\n84343571729\n02/04/2024 Bill Payment 1,000.00 805.12\nUHJN-5520380040396554 : I-BANK']
['03/04/2024', 'Payments / Collections 10.08 795.04\nHU INSURANCE UK\nG0003406201 56171304 2024-04-17\nG3406201']
['04/04/2024', '']
['04/04/2024', 'FAST Payment / Receipt 12,000.00 12,795.04\nINVEST\n20240404CIBBSTSTBRT3273519\nOTHER\n04/04/2024 Bill Payment 333.00 12,462.04\nGBU -09890340922 : I-BANK']

Desired outcome: (there should be 6 lists)
['02/04/2024', 'Funds Transfer 56.00 1,805.12', 'TOP-UP TO WALLET! :', '84343571729']
['02/04/2024', 'Bill Payment 1,000.00 805.12', 'UHJN-5520380040396554 : I-BANK']
['03/04/2024', 'Payments / Collections 10.08 795.04', 'HU INSURANCE UK', 'G0003406201 56171304 2024-04-17', 'G3406201']
...
...
['30/04/2024', 'Interest Earned 0.18 2,385.42']


Please provide all 6 lists. Don't make us fill in the gaps.

Your calculation for end_index starts at the same place as start_index did - so it will get the same index if you have two consecutive dates that are the same in date_matches. Set the second parameter of find() for end_index to be start_index and it will then find the next distinct occurrence.

OK, so you've described the task, but what's the question? SO is a Q&A site after all; check out the [tour] if you haven't already. Maybe you want to ask something like "How do I select text between two regex matches when the matched text is the same?" See [ask] for tips.

"end before the next date" - That includes when there is no next date, yeah? as in the last line? Just making sure.

@wjandrea yes that includes when there is no next date i.e. last transaction. I believe you have articulated what i really needed to ask, as it seems problem happens when there are more than one matches

One option is to use re.split to break up the text by date:
import re

input_text = """
02/04/2024 Funds Transfer 56.00 1,805.12
TOP-UP TO WALLET! :
84343571729
02/04/2024 Bill Payment 1,000.00 805.12
UHJN-5520380040396554 : I-BANK
03/04/2024 Payments / Collections 10.08 795.04
HU INSURANCE UK
G0003406201 56171304 2024-04-17
G3406201
04/04/2024 FAST Payment / Receipt 12,000.00 12,795.04
INVEST
20240404CIBBSTSTBRT3273519
OTHER
04/04/2024 Bill Payment 333.00 12,462.04
GBU -09890340922 : I-BANK
30/04/2024 Interest Earned 0.18 2,385.42
"""

# Build an iterator of the text splitting on lines starting with the date.
i = iter(re.split(r'\s*^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s*', input_text, flags=re.MULTILINE))
next(i)  # Skip the first empty string.
for date in i:  # read the date
    lines = next(i).splitlines()  # get the lines after the date
    print([date, *lines])

Output:
['02/04/2024', 'Funds Transfer 56.00 1,805.12', 'TOP-UP TO WALLET! :', '84343571729']
['02/04/2024', 'Bill Payment 1,000.00 805.12', 'UHJN-5520380040396554 : I-BANK']
['03/04/2024', 'Payments / Collections 10.08 795.04', 'HU INSURANCE UK', 'G0003406201 56171304 2024-04-17', 'G3406201']
['04/04/2024', 'FAST Payment / Receipt 12,000.00 12,795.04', 'INVEST', '20240404CIBBSTSTBRT3273519', 'OTHER']
['04/04/2024', 'Bill Payment 333.00 12,462.04', 'GBU -09890340922 : I-BANK']
['30/04/2024', 'Interest Earned 0.18 2,385.42']

